# How to display UITextLabels like (checkmark) on cell when UITableViewCell tapped?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm working on a UITableView that acts like checklist. I have managed to display UITextLabel when UITableViewCell tapped and hide UITextLabel like (Checkmark) when UITableViewCell tapped again.

When I close the app it does display UITextLabel before tapped.

Took screenshots of the app:

[image]
[image]

Now I have some code that makes this work:

// 1

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for: indexPath)
    let category = categories[indexPath.row]


    // cell.secondTextLabelType = hide/display
    if category.done {
        cell.textLabel?.text = category.name
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = ""
    }


    return cell
}

// 2
//hide and display the TextField2
func setItemStatus(item:Category) {
    let status = item.done ? false : true

    item.done = status

}
// 3
//MARK - TableView Delegate Methods

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //categories goes here
    let item = categories[indexPath.row]

    //cell?.twoItems = hide/display
    setItemStatus(item: item)
    tableView.reloadData()

    saveCategories()

}
```

Comment: so what do you want to do ?

Comment: if you tap item .. and it goes away .. it will remain at this position even you close the app ? is that something you want ?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Yes, that’s exactly what I’m looking for.

Comment: for that you need to persist data ... are you doing that ?

Comment: I did manage to persist data but the app I am working on requires Cora data.

Comment: so you persist data in coredata ?

Comment: Sorry that was UserDefaults, It was not Cora Data.

Comment: so you are saving categories in userDefault ?

Comment: The thing is I was using UserDefaults before for my Todolist app but I have realised that UserDefaults can not cope a lot stuff so, I had to switch to Cora Data.

Comment: but for now `saveCategories()` what is this function doing ?

Comment: I want the app to remain at this position even I close it.

Comment: saveCategories() that's right.

Comment: please write this method here ? saveCategories() and getMethod as well

Comment: Sorry I didn't getMethod? and also where shall I write this method. Would you mind if I share the file with you?

Comment: no i dont mind ... share it